# Cutting sound in actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio

I know how to record audio in actionscript 3. But is it possible to cut away something from the final sound file in actionscript?

My use case is, that the user can jump to a specific point in the sound file (i can manage that) and start recording from there (essentially overwriting the rest of the file).

Is this possible in actionscript 3. If yes, how?

Thank you.

UPDATE:

This is the code I've used, and it works, but the old recording gets pitched down. I don't know why. "selectedTime" is a millisecond value of a time the user selected in a graphical representation of the wave; 44100 is my sample rate.

```
existingByte = new ByteArray();
var extract:Number = Math.floor ((selectedTime)*44.1);
sound.extract(existingByte, extract);

mic.recordData(existingByte);

// in the mic class:
public function recordData(existingByteArray:ByteArray=null):void {
    if(existingByteArray == null) {
        raw = new ByteArray();
    } else {
        raw = existingByteArray;
        raw.position = raw.length;
    }
    mic.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, dataHandler);           
}

private function dataHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void {
    try {
        raw.writeBytes(event.data);               
    } catch(e) {
        this.stopRecording();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  As you are receiving bytes in from the audio stream you are appending those into the master buffer.  If you want to do a punch-in like recording.  You'll need to know the offset into the master buffer where you want to punch into.  So instead of writing to the buffer from the start, you'd write to the buffer from the offset the user clicked.  You'll have to relate the mouse pointer to an offset in your master buffer.  Then as you receive new audio simply overwrite the values in that buffer.  If you want a punch-out so it only overwrites a small section of the audio.  You'll need a end point in the master buffer where to stop writing new data as well.  The user could highlight a section of the audio to get in/out points say.

You'll have to use ByteArrays for the two buffers.  You can extract the raw bytes from Sound using Sound.extract().  Other sources of raw audio can be applied here as well:

```
var master : ByteArray;  // assume this is loaded with some audio

public function punchIn( startLocation : index, sound : Sound ) : void {
    sound.extract( master, sound.bytesTotal, startLocation );
}
```

By varying the length parameter you could do a punch in and punch out feature.

Comment: Okay thank you. I'll try and will surely come back with some sample code :)

Comment: This is cool, but I have one remaining problem. It works perfect and I have managed to do the cut. I use the master and pass it back to my microphone class, and add the new recording at the end. 

Please check my question again, I've added the code.

While this works, the pitch of the inital recording is signifigantly lower. 

I'm calculating the length like this: sound.length * 44.1 (44.1 is my rate).

Do you have an idea why this happens.

Thank you so much so far!!!

Comment: You have a mismatch in sample rates between the mic input and the sample file you are loading into your buffer.  If your Sound is 44.1khz then your mic has to be 44.1khz.  I'm pretty sure mic isn't sampled at 44.1khz.  So you'll need to downsample the 44.1khz buffer to the same sample frequency of the mic. That's looping over the Sound raw bytes and extracting every N bytes into the master.  indexStep = 44.1khz / 16khz. You might have to accumulate the round off errors and take an extra byte every X seconds. Keep a float and add up remainders if (acc > 1.0) { acc -= 1.0; sampleExtraByte() }

Comment: But the sample file is recorded with the Mic as well. However, I will look if the library I m using changes something. I'm on the bus right now but will try ASAP ( it does sound complicated ...), Thanks for your ongoing support.

Comment: I have looked through the code and am now explicitly setting the microphone rate to 44 (which is 44.100). If I set it to 22, the record (even in the first place) get doubled. 

Is it possible that it captures in another rate no matter what? How can I check? How can I check the sample rate from the sound object! 

Is it possible that it has something to do with stereo / mono?

Thank you!

Comment: I've seen that sound is always 44.100 when extracted. So how can I check if the microphone rate of 44 is really assinged?

Comment: Because I know guess it's this mono/stereo thing, i've posted a new question, to keep this one clean; as it answers my original question:

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912631/how-to-extract-sound-object-to-a-mono-byte-array-in-as3)