# How to extract sound object to a mono byte array in AS3

Tags: audio, actionscript, arrays, microphone

I'm trying to prepend the byte array of a sound object to a captured microphone sound byte array.

It works, but the extracted sound object get pichted down and doubled in length. I guess this is because the byte array of the sound object is in stereo, while the mic byte array is in mono.

I have this:

```
sound.extract(myByteArray, extract);
```

myByteArray now contains the stereo data. How can I turn this to mono (I'm new to ByteArrays).

UPDATE:

Here's a working solution:

```
existingByte.position = 0;
var mono : ByteArray = new ByteArray();
while(existingByte.bytesAvailable) {
    var left : Number = existingByte.readFloat();
    mono.writeFloat(left);
    existingByte.position +=4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pick a channel to extract.  I think ByteArray is interleaved so if you pick all odd bytes its the left channel, if you pick all even bytes it's the right channel.

```
var mono : ByteArray = new ByteArray();
for( var i : int = 0; i < raw.length; i+=2 ) {
    var left : int = raw[i];
    var right : int = raw[i+1];

    var mixed : int = left * 0.5 + right * 0.5;
    if( pickLeft ) {
      mono.writeByte( left );
    } else if( pickRight ) {
      mono.writeByte( right );
    } else {
      mono.writeByte( mixed );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, the wave writer class that I'm using (provided by Adobe) fires the following error, if I'm using your code:

Error: Audio samples not in float format
 at classes::WAVWriter/processSamples()

Comment: Yes my "code" wasn't right.  Reading bytes would mean everything is 8bit.  A float is 16bit so yes you'd need to read alternating floats (not bytes if the stream is 16bit), but the idea of picking the left channel, right channel, or mixing them is still valid.