# as3 bytearray splice

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, splice

I'm pretty much an actionscript novice and I'm trying just slice the first and last X bytes out of a byte array in as3, and can't seem to find anything anywhere on how to do that.

If it matters, the byte array is a set of floats recorded from a microphone that I'm trying to cut the first and last 1/4 of a second off of before it's encoded as a .wav file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you an existing ByteArray, let's call it rawBytes:

```
var trimmedBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var quarterSecond:int = 1000; // no. bytes per 1/4 second (arbitrary estimate)
rawBytes.readBytes(trimmedBytes, quarterSecond, rawBytes.length - quarterSecond * 2);
```

Your trimmedBytes variable will now be populated with the second recording minus the first and last quarter second - assuming that quarterSecond variable has the right value. I don't know what that value should be, I'd imagine it would depend on the bitrate at which you're recording. You could probably get there via trial and error though!

Comment: Awesome, I knew there must be some simple way. Thanks.

Comment: @hobberwickey did this solution worked for you? For me not. Wav file becomes corrupted when i cut first bytes.

Comment: This post helped me [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897154/cutting-sound-in-actionscript)